# apply a hover border to an image

Tags: css, hover, mousehover

I'm not able to get a hover on my images to work, I'm sure I'm targeting the css hover incorrectly, but I also have some jquery that is attached the the images which may be causing the conflict.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLS1984/9zwsJ/

Basically I just the border to appear on a hover state.

Comment: Your selector is off "#content #team img.teaming a:hover".  Notice how it's applying it to an anchor that's a descendant of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#content #team a:hover img.teamimg {
   padding:3px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/KB9S4/

Answer (score 2):

Two things appear wrong to me.

Your `a` is outside the image but your selector is looking for it inside.  Also, you have a typo: `teaming` and `teamimg` don't match up.

So change:

```
#content #team img.teaming a:hover {
```

to

```
#content #team a:hover img.teamimg {
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
#content #team a:hover img.teamimg
```

You had:

```
#content #team img.teaming a:hover
```

Two things wrong with this.  First `teaming` is wrong, it's `teamimg` (an m not an n).  2nd, the `img` comes before the `a`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/9zwsJ/14/

```
#content #team a.panel3:hover img {
   padding:3px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mis-ordering this style:

```
#content #team img.teaming a:hover
```

img.teaming is *inside* the  tag, therefore it should read:

```
#content #team a:hover img.teaming
```

I don't believe that will work in all browsers, however (ie?). If you know all the links in that unordered list are going to contain images, you could just apply the border to the a tag itself:

```
#content #team a:hover
```

or

```
#content #team a.panel13:hover
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `img` is inside the `a`, so you want to target the `a` and move it before the `img` in the CSS selector. You can see my work here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/9zwsJ/16/